# Serve static files in warp that are bundled in the executable?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I am writing an application using Warp with Rust for a while now, and I want to pack it into a standalone executable but the `warp::fs::dir` seems to load it from filesystem, as the name suggests.

Is there any way to bundle the static files as a warp filter? Or is there any other framework that supports this?

Just to clarify, by "bundle" i mean something like this:

```rust
fn get_file() -> &str {
    include_str!("file.html")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for `static_dir` macro from [`static_dir` crate](https://crates.io/crates/static_dir).

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.rs/static_dir/latest/static_dir/macro.static_dir.html):

> Creates a Filter that serves a directory at the base `$path` joined by
> the request path.
>
> It behaves much like warp’s `fs::dir`, but instead of serving files from
> the filesystem at runtime, the directory to be served will be embedded
> into your binary at compile time.
>
> If the provided path is relative, it will be relative to the project
> root (as per the `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` environment variable).
>
> ```
> use static_dir::static_dir;
> use warp::Filter;
>
> // Matches requests that start with `/static`, and then uses the
> // rest of that path to lookup and serve a file from `/www/static`.
> let route = warp::path("static").and(static_dir!("/www/static"));
>
> // For example:
> // - `GET /static/app.js` would serve the file `/www/static/app.js`
> // - `GET /static/css/app.css` would serve the file `/www/static/css/app.css`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The [`rust-vfs`](https://crates.io/crates/vfs) crate has support for an `EmbeddedFS`, that is a filesystem inside the binary itself.

Edit: There is a problem with the documentation link from crates.io, [this](https://docs.rs/vfs/0.9.0/vfs/impls/embedded/struct.EmbeddedFS.html) is the documentation for the EmbeddedFS part.